# C# Socket(server) Receives only half data

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a program like this:

```
class FTServerCode
    {
        IPEndPoint ipEnd;
        Socket sock;
        public FTServerCode()
        {
           ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5656);
           sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
           sock.Bind(ipEnd);
        }
        public static string receivedPath;
        public static string curMsg = "Stopped";
        public  void StartServer()
        {
            try
            {
                curMsg = "Starting...";
                sock.Listen(100);

                curMsg = "Running and waiting to receive file.";
                Socket clientSock = sock.Accept();

                byte[] clientData = new byte[1024 * 5000];

                int receivedBytesLen = clientSock.Receive(clientData);
                curMsg = "Receiving data...";

                int fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(clientData, 0);
                string fileName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(clientData, 4, fileNameLen);

                BinaryWriter bWrite = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(receivedPath +"/"+ fileName, FileMode.Append)); ;
                bWrite.Write(clientData, 4 + fileNameLen, receivedBytesLen - 4 - fileNameLen);

                curMsg = "Saving file...";

                bWrite.Close();
                clientSock.Close();
                curMsg = "Reeived & Saved file; Server Stopped.";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                curMsg = "File Receving error.";
            }
        }
    }
```

This program works but instead of receiving let's say total file size of 600KB it only receives 6KB of file. The program doesn't crash or anything but it only receives small fraction of file. What's wrong?

Comment: define curMsg as local variable btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem :** you are reading only once by calling the `Receive()` one time only.

**Soution :** You need to read the `data` until unless the `Receive` function gives you.use `while` loop to determine whether `data` is available or not.

Try This:

```
    int recv=0;
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];

    StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
    while ((recv=clientSock.Receive(data)) > 0)
    {
        sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv));
    }
```

**Complete Code:**

```
class FTServerCode
{
   IPEndPoint ipEnd;
   Socket sock;
   public FTServerCode()
   {
      ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5656);
      sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
      sock.Bind(ipEnd);
   }
   public static string receivedPath;
   public static string curMsg = "Stopped";
   public  void StartServer()
   {
      try
      {
         curMsg = "Starting...";
         sock.Listen(100);

         curMsg = "Running and waiting to receive file.";
         Socket clientSock = sock.Accept();

         byte[] clientData = new byte[1024];
         StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
         int receivedBytesLen = 0;
         int fileNameLen = 0;
         string fileName = "";
         BinaryWriter bWrite;
         while((receivedBytesLen =clientSock.Receive(clientData))>0)
         {
            curMsg = "Receiving data..."; 
            fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(clientData, 0);
            fileName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(clientData, 4, fileNameLen);

            bWrite = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(receivedPath +"/"+ fileName, FileMode.Append)); ;
            bWrite.Write(clientData, 4 + fileNameLen, receivedBytesLen - 4 - fileNameLen);
         }
         curMsg = "Saving file...";

         bWrite.Close();
         clientSock.Close();
         curMsg = "Reeived & Saved file; Server Stopped.";
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         curMsg = "File Receving error.";
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where should I put the message, inside the loop or outside? Can you put your code on my code.

Comment: @user2032220: i have edited my answer , but please take care after while loop you can write `sb` variable into file @ statement  `//use sb to write into file`, if you can not let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much for the edit. I didn't quite get `sb to write into file` as we are already writing into the file into the while loop. Do I need to make any more changes?

Comment: @user2032220: check my edited answer with `complete code`, it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you need to put this in a loop until the read call returns 0

```
 int receivedBytesLen = clientSock.Receive(clientData);
```